# C# - Same Repository, or split?

Tags: c#, repository, repository-pattern

I have a table named "Case" and therefore also an object named "Case". I also got a table named "CaseReplies" which has many-to-one relationship with the "Case" table - the "CaseReplies" table also have its own object named "CaseReply"

Should I create different repositories for those two, or should they both operate under the repository originally dedicated to the "Case" table/object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repositories should be per aggregate root. 1 to many relationship is super strong sign that Case is aggregate root and case reply is entity (case reply does not exist w/o case).

So - I believe You should have only 1 repository - CaseRepository.

This of course applies only if You are following domain driven design. If not and just trying to abstract away persistence - do as You like.

Comment: CaseRepository inherits IRepository<Case> - How would I then delete a CaseReply from a Case?

Comment: OK, we have one case and it has 20 CaseReplies. You need to update one  CaseReplies, then you pass the whole hierarchy to be updated?

Comment: @ebb You would call `case.DeleteReply(int replyId)` and case repository would save it.

Comment: @Arnis L. - In the repository, how would you delete that Reply?

Comment: @ebb somehow... currently I'm using ORM and it tracks state itself. anyway - this problem should **not** influence Your domain model.

Comment: @Arnis L. - Think I was a bit unclear.. What I meant was actually a continuation of the comment given by @Aliostad. - How would you delete a CaseReply from a Case without getting all the CaseReplies first?

Comment: @ebb case would have only replies related to case. that's why it's called aggregate root - it aggregates related entities. i doubt there would be more than 1k of them. so I wouldn't care about that. unless system is so performance greedy that few milliseconds matters of course.

Comment: Alright.. sounds like my real problem is how to delete a child object from a parent object in EF Code first.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely they will have separate repositories as `CaseReply` can have operations not involving its parent (update, delete).

Also when a case is deleted this needs to be cascaded to the `CaseReply`. If cascading is not set at the database level, this has to be implemented as a transaction hence you need a single `UnitOfWork` passed to both repositories.

**Now I can imagine `CaseManager` class to have access to both repositories and in fact, this could be just one class for both `Case` and `CaseReply` handling all operations related to case or CaseReply.**

---

### (Update)

I was pointed out to a post to avoid using generic repositories. Well I do find using repositories useful and here is how I use it:

What I do is to have a generic repository `IRepository<T>`, then have a `BaseRepository<T>` to implement common repository patterns and do all the database related stuff. This would in fact expose a **protected** `IQueryable<T>` so that individual repositories inheriting it, have convenient access to Linq side of the repo. Now, most likely my individual repository would have very specific interface such as "give me 10 latest orders", "give me orders for this customer only" which I will have as `IOrderRepository`. If `IOrderRepository` needs all or most of `IRepository<T>` interface, I will have `IOrderRepository` : `IRepository<T>`.

Now my `OrderRepository` will be

```
  public class `OrderRepository` : `IOrderRepository`,  `BaseRepository<T>`
  {
      // ...
```

**so that it reuses all the benefits of base repo and also implement a specific repository.**

Comment: The CaseManager in my case must be "CaseService" then.. But Delete/Update is set to cascade at database level, however I'm having trouble deleting a CaseReply from a Case record and started to wonder whether they should have their own Repository before I could do such a thing.

Comment: If we think of Repository as `IRepository<T>` then it is tied to one class so I suggest you stick to that.

Comment: @Aliostad - by that you mean stick with a Repository for each? (One repository for Case and another one for CaseReply)?

Comment: Yes, that I think is the common approach since `IRepository<T>` will represent one class only.